# In Gtk, how can I dynamically set a Window's height and width?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

Before you set `Visible` to `true`, you can use `DefaultWidth` and `DefaultHeight`. But these don't work once the `Window` is visible. You can use `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`, but these prevent the user from shrinking the `Window` below the dimensions you set.

Is there any way to manually change the dimensions of a `Window` once it has been made visible, without enforcing minimum dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`Resize (int width, int height)`](http://www.go-mono.org/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aGtk.Window.Resize(System.Int32%2cSystem.Int32)) method.